# Undefined offset: 0 when looping through array in PHP

Tags: php

I am looping through an array (in PHP) and depending on some string values I push data to some other arrays. This is my code:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= sizeof($matchesAdressRightValues); $x++) {

   $searchSucces = 'Geocoding with parameters';
   $searchUnSucces = 'Unsuccessful';

   //echo(strpos($matchesSuccessRightValues[$x][0], $searchSucces));

   if(strpos($matchesSuccessRightValues[$x][0], $searchSucces) !== FALSE)  {
      array_push($arraySucUnsuc,'success');
      array_push($arrayAddress,$matchesAdressRightValues[$x][0]);
   }
    else if (strpos($matchesSuccessRightValues[$x][0], $searchUnSucces) !== FALSE){
      array_push($arraySucUnsuc,'not_success');
      array_push($arrayAddress,$matchesAdressRightValues[$x][0]);

   }    
}  // end for
```

When I execute this I get a warning message:

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/enomix/www/wind/geocoding/myWebCrawler.php on line *81*

Line 81 is:

```
if(strpos($matchesSuccessRightValues[$x][0], $searchSucces) !== FALSE)
```

If I try to echo the array $matchesSuccessRightValues[$x][0] by putting random values in $x then I get the results correctly. So I know I am not out of index.

My array looks like this:

```
Array
 (
   [0] => Array
      (
        [0] => 28 ΟΚΤΩΒΡΙΟΥ 11,27100,ΗΛΕΙΑ,ΠΥΡΓΟΣ
```

[2015/06/21 03:10:51] Geocoding with parameters: city 
        )

```
   [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => ΜΑΝΩΛΟΠΟΥΛΟΥ 11,27100,ΗΛΕΙΑ,ΠΥΡΓΟΣ
```

[2015/06/21 03:42:54] Geocoding with parameters: city 
        )

```
    [2] => Array..........
```

What is strange is that the size of the newly generated array: $arrayAddress (because although I get warning something is generated!) is smaller than the size of the initial array $matchesAdressRightValues.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: I would `var_dump($matchesSuccessRightValues)` and check if every single nested array has an offset 0.

Comment: Hmm I have 18000 thousand elements..

Comment: remove `<=` from `$x <= sizeof($matchesAdressRightValues)`

Comment: I see now that I have arrays of arrays with no elements inside. That causes the error.

Comment: A `var_dump()` would have showed that, and when there are to many elements you could have made a function to check it for you.